# Android to Java TCP/IP reads too slow

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

So, I've been creating a wireless mouse app that utilizes Bluetooth and WiFi (the user decides), I've recently decided to go from UDP to TCP connection as I noticed one of the mainstream mouse apps uses TCP instead of UDP.

**My problem:** I am sending multiple byte arrays over TCP-IP to my server end but it feels as though there is a lag, is there any way I could potentially speed up how fast I am receiving the byte arrays?

**Server code involving receiving:**

```
Socket client = null;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
try {
    client = serverSocket.accept();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
byte data[] = new byte[2];

if (bis != null) {
    try {
        while(alive && (bis.read(data)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(data[0] + " " + data[1]);

            PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point b = a.getLocation();
            int x = (int)b.getX();
            int y = (int)b.getY();

            dx = data[0];
            dy = data[1];

            newX = x + dx;
            newY = y + dy;

            if(dx == -98 && dy == -98) {
                // Right click
                r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
                r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);

            } else if (dx == -99 && dy == -99) {
                // Left click
                r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            } else if (dx == -97 && dy == -97) {
                // Middle click
                r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
                r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
                Main.wifiDisconnect.doClick();
            } else {
                if (!recieve && (dx != 0 || dy != 0)) { // No current thread and non empty values - Start a new one
                    newX = x + dx;
                    newY = y + dy;
                    i = 0;
                    recieve = true;
                    mmThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while (recieve){
                                r.mouseMove(newX + i * dx, newY + i * dy);
                                r.delay(8);
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    mmThread.start();
                } else if (recieve && dx == 0 && dy == 0) {
                    recieve = false;
                    try {
                        mmThread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mmThread = null;
                } else {
                    newX = x + dx;
                    newY = y + dy;
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Client code (Android) involving sending:**

```
public class sendTask extends AsyncTask<Byte, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Byte ...bytes) {
    try {
        byte x = bytes[0].byteValue();
        byte y = bytes[1].byteValue();
        System.out.println("Message sending: " + x + " " + y);
        byte buf[] = {x, y};
        bos.write(buf); //buffered output stream
        bos.flush();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, get a network sniffer like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and find out for certain what is going on.  It's impossible to *know* without that.

But I will speculate...  TCP has what is called "[Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)" for dealing with small packets.  Basically, it delays the transfer of a small packet on the chance that more data will be ready to send very soon and it can be aggregated into a single larger packet, the overall benefit being a more efficient network connection at the cost of some milliseconds.

You can set the socket option `TCP_NODELAY` to disable this and have all written bytes sent immediately.

Comment: Brian, I shall name my first born child after you. Your solution worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue with my own networked game.

If you send too many packets, there's huge lag. The network in general just can't handle that many packets being thrown around, and with TCP, the next packet can't be sent until the last one is recieved, so the packets just queue up to be sent. It causes a large amount of lag.

I found that when I added a 5 millisecond delay when sending packets, my game was super smooth and worked perfectly.

Dug up the commit: https://github.com/anubiann00b/JourneyOfFear/commit/e9074d31bff235a0a12a9d6a0f8998ed2a817d85

Comment: Completely untrue.  TCP can have multiple packets in flight, as many as could make up the receiver's receive-window size.

Comment: I guess I really don't know why then. But that's the observed behavior, and it worked for me. My explanation does seem a little shoddy though...

Comment: Thanks for the attempt anyways :) However, I tried both solutions and Brian's was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Sleeps in networking code don't solve problems. They only change them.